# Как првильнее написать?

Tags: глаголы

... числится столько-то объектов или числятся столько-то объектов?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать единственное число, так как глагол находится перед счетным оборотом, а существительное является неодушевленным, то есть имеет неактивный характер.

Comment: Считал оба варианта допустимыми, но Ваш ответ логичен, спасибо.